# Doxygen - parameterless functions

Tags: doxygen

I have several functions that do not have a parameter or a return.

When I do something like this:

```
/*!
* @fn
*
* @brief ...
*
* @param None.
*
* @return None.
*/
```

I will get warnings about not knowing what parameter 'None.' is, and the resulting HTML documentation will highlight 'None.' as if it were a literal parameter name.

I would like to be able to explicitly say that I do not have parameters, without leaving the section blank/nonexistent.

How can I specify in the prolog (or the doxygen settings) to generate the Parameters section and use a message instead of specifying a literal parameter?

Comment: As far as I know doxygen does not have facilities for this. You have to create your own ALIAS mimicking this requested behavior (with the help of \par etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`@param[in,out]` is usually reserved to define the input parameters.
As you don't have any, explain this in the detailed description or using the `\remark` command.